# Vote for comments in posts function with Codeigniter and routing

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to create posts with comments with CodeIgniter and I am trying to add voting for the comments with + and -.
But my problem is not actually this functionallity but more exactly creating the link and the method in controller/model for this.

I understand that there is some kind of link to methods.
If I have something like this:

```
public function like() {
    echo 'Test Function';
}
```

and when I create link like this one sitename.com/posts/first-post/like theoritecally I will see blank page with "Test Function" text (and of course if I write proper routing rule but I cannor for now).

I can see a blank page with this working echo 'Test Function', but does this mean I have to load every methods and views for the entire page if I want to display the entire webpage with all the elements? I think that I mistake something very serious here but I don't know what.

The example with the "Create news" tutorial in ellislab.com didnt help me. They show something similar I think with /create/ section in the URL and create() methods.

If I have many links with functionallities do I have to add new routing rules for all of them? I really tried to search in Google and everywhere but I didnt find anything related.

Sorry for this lame question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax call and on callback you have to increase  or decrease the count. For creating a link , once page is loading render the data and provided the default link like

```
for +  http://<site.com>/<controller>/like?totalLike=<36>
for - http://<site.com>/<controller>/unlike?totalunLike=<3>
```

Once user will click + link then by using Ajax, call the controller method link/unlike and increase or decrease the count and repopulate the link again with fresh counter.

Hope it will resolve your problem.